# Can morris.js shows circles only on hover

Tags: morris.js

I'm using morris.js to build charts, but I'm stuck on a problem that I can't figure it out. Is there a way in morris.js to make circles appear only on hover? I read the documentation, but I did not see such an option. To be sure I decide to ask you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `pointSize` to 0. This way, the points will only appear on hover. Run the code snippet to view the result.

```js
Morris.Area({
  element: 'chart',
  data: [
    { y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },
    { y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['Series A', 'Series B'],
  pointSize: 0
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: yes, that is what I needed, thank you for your help @krlzlx.